# ¿Cuál es la convención en Python para los nombres de las variables?

Tags: python, variables

De las siguientes formas de nombrar una variable (o una función), ¿cuál es la más preferible?

- `nombreVariable`
- `nombre_variable`
- `NombreVariable`

¿Hay alguna convención de estilo de código definida en Python?

Comment: Para los que votan para cerrar como "basado en opiniones": Python establece unas normas muy claras para que precisamente no se base en opiniones, sino en estándares. La respuesta lo explica muy claramente, por lo que considero que la pregunta debería dejarse abierta.

Comment: En la primera hora del primer curso de Python que tomas te explican que estilo usar.

Comment: @CandidMoe entonces, ¿por qué se basa en opiniones si es algo consensuado? No entiendo el voto de cierre

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿ves que es una pregunta autorespuesta?

Comment: Oh, lo siento. Sólo revise la pregunta. Retiro mi comentario. Pero, en estricto rigor, la pregunta fue "¿Qué es mejor?", y eso es materia de opiniones. Si hubiera preguntado, "¿Qué es lo recomendado?" sería objetiva.

Comment: @CandidMoe sugiero ser proactivos y mejorar lo mejorable para que el buen contenido prevalezca :P

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/159720/

Comment: He editado y votado por reabrir, @CandidMoe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Variables y funciones**

`nombreVariable` usa [Camel Case](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

`nombre_variable` usa [Snake Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)

`NombreVariable` usa Pascal Case

Según la [guía de estilo de Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), los nombres de variables (y de funciones) deben escribirse en minúscula, con las palabras separadas por un guión bajo (underscore) para mejorar la legibilidad. Es decir, la recomendación es usar Snake Case.

Camel Case se puede utilizar solo para mantener el estilo que se ha utilizado.

Por tanto, `nombreVariable` es correcto solo para mantener el estilo utilizado. `nombre_variable` es la opción recomendada. Se debe evitar escribir `NombreVariable`.

---

**Clases**

En cambio, los nombres de las clases se escriben con la letra inicial mayúscula y se usa Pascal Case: `class NombreClase():`